# How to set mavenLocal in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Within Gradle, I have been setting my repositories like so:

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "http://eqnyknexus002.company.com:8080/nexus/content/groups/main"
  }
}
```

and I realized that it would be great to be able to set it simply as

```
repositories {
  maven {
    mavenLocal() 
  }
}
```

How can I set mavenLocal within a build script so that I can declare it just once use mavenLocal instead of trying to remember the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mavenLocal()` is already used in gradle to point to your local maven repository on your disk (usually at ~/m2/repository folder)

The easiest way to store the url of your local enterprise repo at a central place is to put it in your gradle.properties file:

```
MVN_REPO_URL=http://eqnyknexus002.company.com:8080/nexus/content/groups/main
```

Then you can just reference this property in your build files

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url MVN_REPO_URL
    }
}
```